# What way to pass trough data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm working with Tensorflow but I'm pretty new to Python and machine learning. If I have a tensor of an image from my input pipeline what would be the best way to train it? Like in the basics, how would I handle passing trough data? I have structure I would like to use (I know I can get certain data from certain things like tensors) but I'm just not sure how to do so.

I'm very new to this so all help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def model(image_tensor):
    tf.summary.image(img)

    return predictions

def loss(predictions, labels):

    return some_loss

def train(some_loss):

    return train_op
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow may be a bit complicated for someone new to machine learning and python.  My advice is to go through the excellent notebook tutorials that exist on tensorflow sites and start to understand the abstraction.

However, before that, I would use python with numpy (and sometimes scipy) to implement basic machine methods like Stochastic Gradient Descent just to ensure that you understand how the algorithms work.  Then implement a simple logistic regression.

So why do I ask you to do all that?  Well, because once you get a good handle of how to work with machine learning algorithm and how tedious it can be find the gradients, you will understand why tensorflow abstraction is useful.

I'm going to provide you with some simple examples dealing with MNIST.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


mnist = load_digits(2)
print("y [shape: {}] {}] : {}".format(y.shape,y[:10]))
print("x [shape: {}] {}]".format(x.shape)
```

What i've essentially done above is load two digits from the MNIST dataset (0 and 1) and display the array for the vector y and matrix (x). 
If you want to see how the images look you can `plt.imshow(X[0].reshape([8,8]))` 
The next step is to start defining our placeholder and variables

```
input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,X.shape[1]], name     = "input_x")
input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,],name = "labels")
weights = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.zeros(shape=[X.shape[1],1]), name="weights")
b = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.0, name = "bias")
```

We have done here is defined two placeholder in tensorflow and have told what the variables should expect as an input.  I also gave the placeholder a name for debugging purpose.

```
prediction_y = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(input_x,weights),tf.cast(b,tf.float32))))
loss = tf.losses.log_loss(input_y,prediction_y)
optimizer = tf.train.Adamoptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)
```

There you go, that's a logistic regression in tensorflow.  What the last block does is apply the activation function to our input vectors, defines the loss function and then defines an optimizer for the loss function.

The final step is to run it.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(10):
    s.run(optimizer,{input_X:X_train, input_y: y_train})
    loss_i = s.run(loss, {input_x:x_train,input_y:y_train})
    print("loss at iteration {}: {}".format(i, loss_i))
```

That's essentially how you run your data through tensorflow.  This code may have typos, I don't have python on this machine so i'm writing based on memory.  However the basic idea is there.  Hope this helps.

Edit:  Also since you asked best way to train image data.  My answer to you would be there isn't a "best".  Building a CNN is a typical approach that you may want to experiment using assuming you have large number of classified images.  Prior to that people also used support vectors relatively well for classifying images.